# unknown column in where clause with case + union + like

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I am working on sql query in mysql . My query is like this,

```
select reqId,sDate,stitle,sType,status,reqUser,assignedTo from 
(select request_id as reqId,date as sDate,title as sTitle,type as sType,status as status,request_user as reqUser ,
case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
     when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
     when status='approved' then fbAdmin.name
     when status='rejected' then fbAdmin.name
else null
end as assignedTo
from fb_requests fr
left join users fbuser on (fr.reqUser = fbuser.id)
left join users fbmanager on (fr.managerid= fbmanager.id)
left join users fbAdmin on (fr.adminin = fbAdmin.id)
where 1=1
and ( upper(assignedTo) like upper('abc') )
UNION
select request_id as reqId,date as sDate,title as sTitle,type as sType,status as status,request_user as reqUser ,
case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
     when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
else null
end as assignedTo
from fb_wall_posts fw
left join users fbuser on (fw.request_by_id = fbuser.id)
left join users fbmanager on (fw.manager_id= fbmanager.id)
 where 1=1
and ( upper(assignedTo) like upper('abc') ))
```

here I am getting 'unknown column assignedTo' . can anyone help me out how to resolve this. Thanks in advance for valueble reply.

Comment: looks like the stitle and sTitle case sensitive?

Comment: The first subquery does upper(assignedTO) but assignedTo isn't a value in fb_requests, fbuser,fbmanager, or fbadmin.  It's a derived value based on status and names.  Thus you need to use the same case statement in teh where clause as the order of operations stipulate the table joins occur first then the where clause.  So the select and derived alias isn't in scope at the time the where clause is being evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use alias name in where condition (you can use alias in order by and in some mysql version in group by) when you need  you must repeat the code

```
  select reqId,sDate,stitle,sType,status,reqUser, assignedTo from 
  (select request_id as reqId,date as sDate,title as sTitle,type as sType,status as status,request_user as reqUser ,
  case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
       when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
       when status='approved' then fbAdmin.name
       when status='rejected' then fbAdmin.name
  else null
  end as assignedTo
  from fb_requests fr
  left join users fbuser on (fr.reqUser = fbuser.id)
  left join users fbmanager on (fr.managerid= fbmanager.id)
  left join users fbAdmin on (fr.adminin = fbAdmin.id)
  where 1=1
  and ( upper(
        case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
           when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
           when status='approved' then fbAdmin.name
           when status='rejected' then fbAdmin.name
      else null
      end
  ) like upper('abc') )
  UNION
  select request_id as reqId,date as sDate,title as sTitle,type as sType,status as status,request_user as reqUser ,
  case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
       when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
  else null
  end as assignedTo
  from fb_wall_posts fw
  left join users fbuser on (fw.request_by_id = fbuser.id)
  left join users fbmanager on (fw.manager_id= fbmanager.id)
   where 1=1
  and ( upper(
    case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
       when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
      else null
    end
    ) like upper('abc') ))
```

Answer (score 1):

AssignedTo hasn't been defined when the where clause executes, so you have to use the complete case statement as the alias hasn't been created yet.

```
select reqId,sDate,stitle,sType,status,reqUser,assignedTo from 
(select request_id as reqId,date as sDate,title as sTitle,type as sType,status as status,request_user as reqUser ,
case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
     when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
     when status='approved' then fbAdmin.name
     when status='rejected' then fbAdmin.name
else null
end as assignedTo
from fb_requests fr
left join users fbuser on (fr.reqUser = fbuser.id)
left join users fbmanager on (fr.managerid= fbmanager.id)
left join users fbAdmin on (fr.adminin = fbAdmin.id)
where 1=1
and ( upper(case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
     when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
     when status='approved' then fbAdmin.name
   ) like upper('abc') )
UNION
select request_id as reqId,date as sDate,title as sTitle,type as sType,status as status,request_user as reqUser ,
case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
     when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
else null
end as assignedTo
from fb_wall_posts fw
left join users fbuser on (fw.request_by_id = fbuser.id)
left join users fbmanager on (fw.manager_id= fbmanager.id)
 where 1=1
and ( upper(case when status='posted' then fbuser.name
     when status='awaiting approval' then fbmanager.name
     when status='approved' then fbAdmin.name
   ) like upper('abc') ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis before the UNION keyword.